# Perfect shuffle algorithm implementation error

Tags: java

Is this code correct for perfect shuffle algorithm ? I'm always trying to generate a number from 0 to n and swapping the number with the last element in the array thereby reducing the range of n. However when the n=0, I get an exception. How do I deal with this case ?

```
    int [] array ={1,2,3,4,5};
    Random random = new Random();
    int n=array.length;

    while(n--!=0)
    {
        int number = random.nextInt(n);
        int temp = array[n];
        array[n] = array[number];
        array[number] = temp;
    }
```

EDIT: if I change it to --n >0 then it works correctly but am I implementing the shuffling algorithm correctly in that case because I never do anything for n=0 ?

Comment: When you say "n=0" do you mean that n is equal to 0 before the while loop? As in, there are no elements in the array?

Answer (score 1):

In your code segment

```
   while(n--!=0) 

 if n is 1, it will become 0 and `random.nextInt(0)` will return an error.
```

[Refer this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think nextInt works if you pass an argument of 0.

The best way to shuffle is by using the [Fisher Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle).  It's fast, works in-place, and is unbiased:

```
int [] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
Shuffle(array, new Random());

// Fisher Yates shuffle - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle
void Shuffle(int[] array, Random RNG)
{
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 1; i -= 1)
    {
        // get integer in range of j >= 0 && j < i + 1
        int j = RNG.nextInt(i + 1);
        //assert(j >= 0 && j <= i);
        if (i != j)
        {
            // only swap if i and j are different
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```